# What are the G limits of the accelerometer in a Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

From what I've read while searching for an answer, the readings of a Windows Phone accelerometer are expressed in G's. What I've searched for and could not find is the limits of the sensor / the limits imposed by the SDK.

I mean does it support G forces of like 5G or 8G or is it limited to 1G only?
Thank you very much.

Comment: could anyone test this on a real device and see what G forces they get? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not limited in `1G`. `1G` is gravity force, so it applies all the time. The limit of force that accelerometer capable of measure is exists, but it much higher that `1G` and, I think, it varies on different devices (depends of chip manufacturer and model)